# simplify Unity Container Resolve expression

Tags: c#, dependencies, unity-container

I am new to dependency injection and Microsoft Unity IoC. My scenario is the follwing:

Employee-Class:

```
class Employee
{
    private readonly ISalaryCalculation _salaryCalculationCalculator;

    public Employee(ISalaryCalculation salaryCalculationCalculator)
    {
        _salaryCalculationCalculator = salaryCalculationCalculator;
        BaseSalary = 42;
    }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int BaseSalary { get; set; }

    public int CalcSalary()
    {
        return _salaryCalculationCalculator.CalcSalary(BaseSalary);
    }
}
```

I have two different implementations of my SalaryCalculation-Interface

```
interface ISalaryCalculation
{
    int CalcSalary(int baseSalary);
}
```

My Unity setup is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<Employee>();

    unityContainer.RegisterType<ISalaryCalculation, BossSalaryCalculation>("Boss");
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ISalaryCalculation, NormalSalaryCalculation>("Normal");

    var employee = unityContainer.Resolve<Employee>(new DependencyOverride(typeof(ISalaryCalculation),unityContainer.Resolve<ISalaryCalculation>("Boss")));
    Console.WriteLine(employee.CalcSalary());
}
```

Is there a smarter way to achiev this by using Unity? Because whenever I instantiate a new Employee, I have to pass its salaryCalculation logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register only one implementation depending on some condition:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<Employee>();

    if (someCondition)
    {
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ISalaryCalculation, BossSalaryCalculation>("Boss");
    }
    else
    {
        unityContainer.RegisterType<ISalaryCalculation, NormalSalaryCalculation>("Normal");
    }
    var employee = unityContainer.Resolve<Employee>();
    Console.WriteLine(employee.CalcSalary());
}
```

Another way - to use ResolvedParameter:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UnityContainer unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
    unityContainer.RegisterType<Employee>();

    unityContainer.RegisterType<ISalaryCalculation, BossSalaryCalculation>("Boss");
    unityContainer.RegisterType<ISalaryCalculation, NormalSalaryCalculation>("Normal");

    var employee = unityContainer.Resolve<Employee>(new ParameterOverride("salaryCalculationCalculator", new ResolvedParameter<ISalaryCalculation>("Boss")));
    Console.WriteLine(employee.CalcSalary());
}
```